# Uniquely Identifying FT232H Chips

Tags: ftdi, serial-number

I have a few FTDI FT232H breakout boards from Adafruit. I wanted to connect multiple of them through a USB hub. I was under the impression that the serial number is unique and based on "The serial number consists of 8 characters, the first two being the manufacturer ID and the next 6 being base 36 numbers based on the date and exact time of programming." as per https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?howistheautomaticserialnu.htm.

But when I run my code to identify the devices. I see

```
Channel number: 0
Description: FT232H
Serial: FTKIJX5M
ID: 67330068
LocId: 13377

Channel number: 1
Description: FT232H
Serial: FT3ZQ7NY
ID: 67330068
LocId: 214084

Channel number: 2
Description: FT232H
Serial: FT3ZQ7NY
ID: 67330068
LocId: 36

Channel number: 3
Description: FT232H
Serial: FTOVSJUB
ID: 67330068
LocId: 35

Channel number: 4
Description: FT232H
Serial: FTOVSJUB
ID: 67330068
LocId: 13378
```

As you can see I have two FT3ZQ7NY, and two FTOVSJUB, and one FTKIJX5M, is there a way to make it unique because all my devices and attached peripherals are identical in nature. Is there any way to uniquely identify the device?

Comment: possibly knock-offs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve it to program the FTDI chip using FT Prog that you can download from https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG

1. Select the device in the device tree
2. Select the USB String Descriptors
3. Uncheck Auto Generate Serial Number
4. Enter a Custom Serial Number
5. Click on the program button (which looks like a lightning bolt in silver color)

Now you can get it in unique numbers, or you can auto-assign the serial numbers based on the unique timestamp of programming.

```
Channel number: 0
Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
Serial: FT58FK0A
ID: 67330068
LocId: 13377

Channel number: 1
Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
Serial: FT58FK0B
ID: 67330068
LocId: 214084

Channel number: 2
Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
Serial: FT58FK0C
ID: 67330068
LocId: 36

Channel number: 3
Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
Serial: FT58FK0D
ID: 67330068
LocId: 13378

Channel number: 4
Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
Serial: FT58FK0E
ID: 67330068
LocId: 13378
```

Comment: Note this may not work with counterfeit (not genuine FTDI) parts.